# How to use a for loop with an integer

Tags: vb.net, for-loop, int32

I'm trying to add an option to do something a set amount of times, but I couldn't get an int32 to work with it. I'm using

`dim Int As Int32()
For i = 0 To Int
'code
Next i`

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Could you please share a full snippet?

Comment: [Some tutorial for you](http://www.dotnetperls.com/for-vbnet)

Comment: Also refer to the MSDN documentation. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5z06z1kb.aspx

Comment: Well, you could start by a) not using a confusing variable name like `Int`, which can be confused with an actual data type, and b) giving your variable a value before trying to use it as the upper bound of a loop. What **specific problem** other than failing to do other than that do you have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides being poorly named, with the parenthesis after `Int32()` you're actually declaring an **Array** of Int32.  You probably just wanted a single Int32, in which case you should get rid of the parenthesis and also give it a value:

```
    Dim NumberOfTimes As Int32 = 3
    For i As Int32 = 1 To NumberOfTimes
        MessageBox.Show("Hello " & i.ToString)
    Next i
```

Comment: Yeah, I realized that that was an array a while after I posted this. Sorry for the wait, and thanks for the declaration help.